# processing loyalty swipe cards in square

Tags: square-connect

I was taking a look at the Square API.  I am trying to find a solution for VIP/loyalty cards for a private club.  I feel like the square API would be useful.  What I am trying to figure out is if it is possible to read data from a gift card/security card in the API.  My Idea is to use the reader in two places, at the front door to verify VIP status and for payment.  Ideally, the card would have a member id that could be linked to a Facebook account, as well as looking up saved payment info in Square. I would like to use the API to build a tablet app to manage all of these functions as well as provide discounts prior to payment processing.

I noticed mentions of 3rd party gift card support, does that mean this would be possible?  or is the data for non credit card swipes still locked down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get card data from the readers. The gift card support is only for payments.

Comment: Well, that sucks, I was hoping to use an al in one solution, I will have to look around for other card reader solutions. Is there any chance this could be implemented in the future?  I understand the need for locking and encrypting credit card data, but if there was a way for the reader to allow access to card data that was not a credit card, the platform could be used in ways square may not even think of.

Comment: I wouldn't hold your breath 

Comment: Or, I do know that there is a square gift card,  would it be possible to use square's own gift card solutions? is there a unique gift card ID that can be accessed by the API?  I would imagine that it would be seen by the api for customer tracking purposes.

Comment: Not really. You would likely have better luck with a RFID/QR/OCR solution

Comment: Ok, I appreciate it.

Comment: One other question, how trivial is it to set up saved cards in square and apply discounts/process payments using the API.  The documentation is a little sparse.  What kind of other information and resources is available?

Comment: I'd keep poking around the documentation. I think it is pretty easy, but I have quite a bit of bias

Comment: Would love to know what documentation you expected to see though.